# mvc controller is passing in null from javascript object that has data

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an MVC controller that somehow is passing in **Null** to it

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateAllNodes(IEnumerable<ReportGroup> reportGroups)
{
    // this is custom return..
    return JsonCamel(null);
}
```

**PROBLEM** :   **reportGroups**  is **null**

**javascript ajax post**

```
$.post(updateAllNodeUri, JSON.stringify({ reportGroups: homogeneous.data() }));
```

**Chrome Dev Tools Form Data:**

```
{"reportGroups":[
    {"Id":1,"ReportGroupName":"Standard Reports","ReportGroupNameResID":null,"SortOrder":1,"items":[],"index":0},
    {"Id":2,"ReportGroupName":"Custom Reports","ReportGroupNameResID":null,"SortOrder":2,"items":[],"index":1},
    {"Id":3,"ReportGroupName":"Retail Reports","ReportGroupNameResID":null,"SortOrder":3,"items":[],"index":2},
    {"Id":4,"ReportGroupName":"Admin Reports","ReportGroupNameResID":null,"SortOrder":5,"items":[],"index":3},
    {"Id":5,"ReportGroupName":"QA Reports","ReportGroupNameResID":null,"SortOrder":4,"items":[],"index":4},
    {"ReportGroupName":"Node","index":5}
]}:
```

So I have the reportGroups in controller along with the JSON as reportGroups:   thus I'm lost on why it is null.

Also here here the **poco** class for the **ReportGroup**

```
public class ReportGroup : BaseEntity
{
    public override int Id { get; set; }
    public string ReportGroupName { get; set; }
    public int? ReportGroupNameResID { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
}
```

Kendo data calls , then I can output to console and see the data as well

```
console.log(homogeneous.data());

// ###  Send the Data to the server 

var updateAllNodeUri = "/Report/UpdateAllNodes";
```

Comment: BTW,  this IS using Kendo UI , thus you see it ADDS some stuff :   items and index  .   These are NOT in my poco class,  but should that matter?

Comment: If you stringify the data, you also need to set the `contentType: 'json'` option - try using the `$.ajax()` method to include this option.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the JSON data you get from Chrome Dev Tools, you are actually sending the JSON with this model:

JSON:

```
{"reportGroups":[
    {"Id":1,"ReportGroupName":"Standard Reports","ReportGroupNameResID":null,"SortOrder":1,"items":[],"index":0},
    {"Id":2,"ReportGroupName":"Custom Reports","ReportGroupNameResID":null,"SortOrder":2,"items":[],"index":1},
    {"Id":3,"ReportGroupName":"Retail Reports","ReportGroupNameResID":null,"SortOrder":3,"items":[],"index":2},
    {"Id":4,"ReportGroupName":"Admin Reports","ReportGroupNameResID":null,"SortOrder":5,"items":[],"index":3},
    {"Id":5,"ReportGroupName":"QA Reports","ReportGroupNameResID":null,"SortOrder":4,"items":[],"index":4},
    {"ReportGroupName":"Node","index":5}
]}:
```

Model:

```
public class ReportGroup
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ReportGroupName { get; set; }
    public object ReportGroupNameResID { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    public List<object> items { get; set; }
    public int index { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<ReportGroup> reportGroups { get; set; }
}
```

The RootObject class is the one being received by your controller which is not the expected parameter.

Try transforming the JSON to this format:

```
[
    {"Id":1,"ReportGroupName":"Standard Reports","ReportGroupNameResID":null,"SortOrder":1,"items":[],"index":0},
    {"Id":2,"ReportGroupName":"Custom Reports","ReportGroupNameResID":null,"SortOrder":2,"items":[],"index":1},
    {"Id":3,"ReportGroupName":"Retail Reports","ReportGroupNameResID":null,"SortOrder":3,"items":[],"index":2},
    {"Id":4,"ReportGroupName":"Admin Reports","ReportGroupNameResID":null,"SortOrder":5,"items":[],"index":3},
    {"Id":5,"ReportGroupName":"QA Reports","ReportGroupNameResID":null,"SortOrder":4,"items":[],"index":4},
    {"ReportGroupName":"Node","index":5}
]
```

Javascript:

```
$.post(updateAllNodeUri, JSON.stringify(homogeneous.data()));
```

Comment: Well if you even mock that up with a simple class and use fiddler, you will see that removing "reportGroups" is not even going to work.  ( I realize that it might not look correct from a pure JSON format with brackets [ ]  , but that is just not it

Comment: The structure you have would work with an without the {"reportGroups": ... with Chrome Extension POSTMAN    -  just his (OP) issue was with the header needed to specify the content-type of json ...